# Why does node.js need significantly more ram than c#?

Tags: .net, memory-management, v8

Today I tested just for fun how much memory the same code would need in a c# command line application compared to Node.js.
This was my code in Node.js:

```
"use strict";

class User{
    constructor(firstname, lastname){
        this.firstName = firstname;
        this.lastName = lastname;
    }
}

const count = 10000000;
const users = [];

console.time('Allocating Elements');

for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    users.push(new User(`John${i}`,`Doe${i}`));
}

console.timeEnd('Allocating Elements');
console.log('Finished');
```

This was my code in C#:

```
class User
    {
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }

        public User(string firstname, string lastname)
        {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var count = 10000000;
            var users = new List<User>();

            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                users.Add(new User($"John{i}", $"Doe{i}"));
            }

            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Allocating Elements: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
            Console.WriteLine("Finished");
        }
    }
```

Both programs where executed as 64bit.

When I used a list of type object in c# the ram consumption was about the same.

So my questions are: **Why does Node need about 4 times as much ram if I use a User class in c#? How is such an optimization possible?**

I attached a screenshot of the ram usage of both processes when they stood in a breakpoint at the end.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNges.png)

Comment: As much as I'm fan of C#/.Net, my experience is that these comparisons tend to turn out to be less meaningful than you'd think. In the end, both are solving similar enough problems that you can usually put enough optimization effort in one or the other to get similar performance, no matter the language or situation. Usually it's some seemingly-silly little change that removes an unexpected performance penalty, or that the behavior or the garbage collector is different such that you find the memory use under load works out the same, but in the test harness it never felt pressure to collect.

Comment: As a case in point: on the C# side, you can get even faster and more memory efficient by pre-allocating that list: (`var users = new List<User>(count);`)

Comment: Well I knew before, that this test is in no way representing real world scenarios. I also know that it doesn't say anything about real world memory usage. But i just wondered and asked myself how these optimizations are possible. Is this possibly just because c# is strictly typed and the compiler can optimize the memory usage?!

Comment: Yeah thats true. The funny thing is node was faster but used way more ram than c#.

Comment: I suspect the problem is the string construction. That's the only way I can see a 4x change in memory, unless node is crazy inefficient about object reference design. But it could also have something to do with how it maintains the internal buffer for the "array". .Net Lists by default start at 10 and use a doubling algorithm as the internal buffer fills up. Under low GC pressure, those intermediate buffers may hang around a while. If Node is similar here, you could end up reallocating a whole new buffer somewhere around 9999999, and use a lot of extra memory. It's just where the breaks fall.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn How does the string construction influence the memory consumption? Maybe a little bit. A char should take 2 bytes of memory in both systems and the strings should already be constructed at this point of time. And i wouldn't say node is inefficient in memory design, cause c# needed nearly the exact same amount of ram if i used a list of type object.

Comment: It can be way different than that. If you used ascii by default on platform and unicode32 on another, that's a 4x difference right there for some strings. However, I don't know Node, but .Net already uses Unicode encoding, so that's unlikely to be the thing here. But what I'm talking about is buffering again. Some platforms are **extremely** inefficient when dealing with strings. .Net used to be one of them, but has cleaned things up over the years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry it took me so long to write. But it seems like I overlooked something. It's embarrassing, but i really didn't see it first. In fact both programs do nearly need the same amount of RAM during execution. My failure was the constructor of the User object in the C# code.

```
    public User(string firstname, string lastname)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
```

I assigned the "firstName" and "lastName" variable to itself and not to the parameters passed to the constructor. Because of this mistake "firstName" and "lastName" was empty during the run. This of course led to a way smaller amount of RAM needed.

Sorry guys. But thanks for the answers. I can't believe i didn't saw that.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment on C#, but I can tell you how much memory V8 consumes for your example. For every `User` object, it'll need:

"User" object itself:

- "hidden class" pointer (object layout description)
- "properties" pointer (to empty backing store)
- "elements" pointer (to empty backing store)
- "firstName" in-object property (to firstNameString, see below)
- "lastName" in-object property (to lastNameString, see below)

firstNameString, lastNameString:

- "hidden class" pointer (identifying this object as a string)
- string hash
- string length
- string characters: "John1234"
- string characters: "567_____"

(string objects are rounded up to pointer size alignment. The first 10,000 "John" strings and the first 100,000 "Doe" strings will only consist of four words each, but compared to the 20,000,000 strings you have in total, that's a negligible effect.)

and finally:

- one slot in the `users` array

When you add it all up, you have 5 + 2*5 + 1 = 16 pointers of 8 bytes each, or 1220MB for 10 million users.
When I run your code in d8 (V8's developer shell) and force a GC in the end to clean up leftover cruft, I see 1258MB consumed. The difference is explained by:

- general environment overhead (JavaScript globals, certain engine internals that get set up on startup)
- some amount of over-allocation of the array backing store (as Joel Coehoorn already pointed out)
- in node.js, my guess is that a much bigger maximum heap size is configured, so the GC doesn't kick in yet. It should clean up more once there's either memory pressure or idle time.